# D3.js Zoom/Pan Functionality with Time Series Chart: Issue with Maintaining Zoom State during Panning

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am currently working on implementing a zoom/pan functionality for a D3.js time series chart. The x-axis of the chart is based on a time series, and I've set up a `d3.scaleTime` for it. The desired behavior is to zoom in and out with the scroll wheel and pan when holding down the Shift key while scrolling or through mouse drag.

I have implemented a zoom function using `d3.zoom()` and have a handler function (`handle_zoom`) to manage the zoom and pan logic. However, I'm encountering an issue where the pan state is not maintained when zooming. It seems that the transform applied during zooming is not saving the pan state, and I suspect I might be approaching the problem incorrectly.

Here is a picure for some context: [Preview of the chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Inb1s.png)

## Relevant code snippets:

### Zoom Function

```
this.zoom_function = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 300])
    .extent([[margin.left, margin.top], [width + margin.left, height + margin.top]])
    .translateExtent([[margin.left, margin.top], [width + margin.left, height + margin.top]])
    .on("zoom", (event) => {this.handle_zoom(event)});
```

### Handle Zoom Function

```
Chart.prototype.handle_zoom = function (event)  {
    const margin = ({top: this.card.config.margin_top, right: this.card.config.margin_right, bottom: this.card.config.margin_bottom, left: this.card.config.margin_left});
    const width = this.card.config.chart_width - margin.left - margin.right;
    const height = this.card.config.chart_height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    let wheel_delta = event.sourceEvent.deltaY * 0.1;

    // Zoom and pan logic here...
    if (event.sourceEvent.shiftKey) {
        // "keep old k"
        // apply wheel_delta to x
        // apply event.transform
    }
    else {
        // apply event.transform
    }

    // Apply the transform to the scaleTime object
    this.x_scale = event.transform.rescaleX(this.x_first);

    // Update chart elements with new scale
    // ...

    // Example for updating scatterplot
    for (const [signal, data] of Object.entries(this.path_data)) {
        // Update scatterplot based on new x_scale
        // ...
    }
    // ...
};
```

### How i create the scaleTime

```
...
// Declare the x (horizontal position) scale function
    this.x_first = d3.scaleTime([xExtents[0],xExtents[1]], [margin.left, width + margin.left]);
    this.x_scale = this.x_first.copy();
...
```

---

I experimented with modifying the actual event within the `handle_zoom` function. Specifically, I modified the `event.transform.x` by simply adding the `wheel_delta` and then applied the new "zoom transform". To prevent an infinite loop, I added a return statement at the beginning of the handler. Unfortunately, this approach did not work.

```
let old_k = 1;
Chart.prototype.handle_zoom = function (event)  {
    // Return statement to prevent infinite loop
    if (/* condition for early return */) {
        return;
    }

    // Modify the event by adjusting x property
    event.transform.x += wheel_delta;

    // Create a new zoom transform
    const transform = d3.zoomIdentity;
    transform.k = event.transform.k;
    transform.x = event.transform.x + wheel_delta;
    transform.y = old_k;

    // Apply the new zoom transform to "save it"
    this.svg.call(this.zoom_function.transform, transform);

    // ...
};
```

Any insights into how i should be soing instead? I also find it difficult to understand why mouse drag "magically" works. Any suggestions on a more effective approach would be greatly appreciated.

## EDIT: Added a better Example

[A Observable example forked from](https://observablehq.com/d/4c82077c2cd5a0f0)  [Here](https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-area-chart)

This somewhat magically works but behaves wierd when paning outside data.

Comment: i suggest you to show a functional sample in snippet code.. it will be eaiser to help you..